# Bias and Variance definitions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining

Is it correct to say that, in the Bias-Variance trade-off:

the **bias** error represents the ability of the model to possibly map the trend of the training set ?

and the **variance** represents how much the model is prone to variations if the dataset changes ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that both the definitions you gave above refer to variance.

**Variance** is an index of **model complexity**. Thus:

high variance -> high complexity -> many degrees of freedom in model -> it overfits training data -> if dataset changes, accuracy degrades a lot

**Bias** is an index of the **systematic error** of the model, as it shows the difference between the expected value of various model's predictions for a given target output **and** the ground truth.

Answer (score 0):

**Bias** are the simplifying assumptions made by a model to make the target function easier to learn.

**Variance** is the amount that the estimate of the target function will change if different training data was used.